# Using javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType Annotation in BeanManaged Transactions

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb-3.0

I got to review a MessageDriven Bean with following Transactions Annotations:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class ODSToBrokerMDB implements MessageListener{
```

After reading again about Bean Managed Transactions in
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnciy.html
I came to the conclusion that the TransactionAttributeType Annotations
makes sense only  in Container Managed Transactions,
although I can't find a Statement in the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html

Do I oversee something? is javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType Annotation in BeanManaged Transactions valid?

Comment: I made a mistake in example above; `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)` should go over the `onMessage` Method

Answer (score 1):

No, `@TransactionAttribute`annotation is only valid for Container Managed Transaction... in your case, that annotation in your Bean Managed Transaction is only noise...

If you read the associated [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttribute.html), it says:

> The TransactionAttribute annotation specifies whether the container is to invoke a business method within a transaction context. The TransactionAttribute annotation can be used for session beans and message driven beans. It can only be specified if container managed transaction demarcation is used.

Comment: I agree, can you refer to a Documentation? this would be great.